# How to write a shell script that searches for patterns

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a quite a few files in my folder,all with .dat extension. How do I write a bash shell script that will do something like this

```
if 2011_ac_.dat then
 do something
if 2002_bc.dat then 
 do something else
```

So depending on `ac` or `bc`,something will be done. Are there regular expressions for shells?

Comment: Depending on what about those file? The files existing? The files having certain contents? What does a regular expression have to do with anything here?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes file already exist,and do something exist,just how to make a selection depending on ac or bc?

Comment: To test whether a file exists (and many other things) you want the `test`/`[` binary/builtin. Like http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: @Cyrus do something is compiled c++!

Comment: I... really haven't the slightest idea what this question is asking. What is `if 2011_ac_.dat` supposed to mean? What do you expect the shell to do when executing that line?

Comment: Yeah. We can't guess what you mean by "something like this". How, exactly, do you decide which files are in the "then" case and which files are in the "else" case?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If file has ac then I perform one code, if it has bc than other.

Comment: @MPejic, in its name? In its contents?

Comment: ...if the name, consider: `for file in *.dat; do case $file in *ac*) echo "$file with ac" ;; *bc*) echo "$file with bc" ;; esac; done`

Comment: However, I'd consider writing this in a completely different way entirely. For instance: `for file in *_ac_*.dat; do echo "$file with ac"; done; for file in *_bc_*.dat; do echo "$file with bc"; done;` -- that way you don't even consider files matching neither pattern. Or: `for file in *_[ab]c_*.dat`, to iterate over both sets in one pass and exclude those files that fall into neither.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In its name.

Comment: @MPejic, consider, next time, putting all that information -- needed to accurately answer the question -- in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in *.dat; do
  if [[ "$file" =~ ac ]]; then
    echo "$file with ac"
  fi
  if [[ "$file" =~ bc ]]; then
    echo "$file with bc"
  fi
done
```

See: `help [[`

Comment: Assuming that this is an accurate read of the OP's (to me, inscrutible) intent, I'd consider a single `case` statement rather than a series of `if`s.